# Microsoft USB dual receiver wireless keyboard (mouse and keyboard center) keeps waking up computer

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, sleep

I have found out what is waking my computer up 1 minute after I click sleep. My Microsoft dual receiver wireless keyboard (mouse and keyboard center) in device manager is the culprit, according to `powercfg devicequery wake_armed`.

If I uninstall it, my computer sleeps like a baby, but then I have no keyboard. Does anyone know how to troubleshoot this? I can disable it completely but that doesn't work. only uninstall gets my rig sleeping peacefully.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  go to Control Panel > Power Options > Under your preferred plan click on Change Plan Settings > Then on Change Advanced Power Settings > Go down the list to SLEEP and Disable "Allow Wake Timers".  This May work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change Advanced Power Settings, USB settings: disable "allow to wake" for the mouse and keyboard.